# Google Sheets Script Custom Sort

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

my range has following values "Postpone","Yes","No". The values need to be sorted in order

1. "Yes"
2. "No"
3. "Postpone".

There is no room for additional columns with 1,2,3 values and worksheet function are also not an option. Is it possible to do this just with Google Aps Script?

Extending the issue:
There is two additional columns that contain text values and need to be sorted ascending. Currently I am doing this way:

`rng.sort([{column: 1, CUSTOM_SORT_NEEDED}, {column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}, ]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what works for me, I used a dictionary. Not sure if best, or nicest but works.

```
function compare(a,b) {
  var crits = {"Yes":1,"No":2,"Postpone":3};

  var col =1;
  var result = 0;

  if (crits[a[col]] > crits[b[col]]) {result = 1}
  else if (crits[a[col]] == crits[b[col]]) {result = 0}
  else {result = -1}

  return result;
}
```